# Check checkboxes are checked in ListView UWP

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have a ListView, that contains 22 CheckBoxes. I should to check all of them, and if checkBox is checked it returns 1, otherwise 0.

```
                 < ListView x: Name = "CheckBoxList" >  
                   < CheckBox x: Name = "nr1" />
                    ...    
                   < CheckBox x: Name = "nr22" />
                  </ListView>
```

And here I send thouse 1 or 0

```
            dynamic sendMessage = MyApi.Api.sendMessage( //for example 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 etc.//);
```

How to make it automatically? Because all I know is how to check it manually (if - else for every control), but it isn't good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of 1,0 can you return true or false. if so you can bind property to IsChecked property of CheckBox. 
If you cant return true or false you have to use value converter

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding values}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding value}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

If you cant return true or false

```
 <Page.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToIntegerConverter x:Key="BooleanToIntegerConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding values}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding value,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToIntegerConverter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Converter**

```
public class BooleanToIntegerConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```